# Java Virtual Machine newbie Confusion: When is the virtual machine invoked while compiling java

Tags: java, jvm

I am just starting to learn java to get into android programming
I assumed that everything that I compile using java gets compiled to java bytecode, which has to be interpreted by the virtual machine. so `javac filename.java` produces `filename.class`, which has the bytecode to be interpreted by the JVM (at least that's what I thought, I would run this class file using java `filename.class`). However, if I write something like this,

```
public class Arrays { 
  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int[] a1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
    int[] a2; 
    a2 = a1; 
    for(int i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) 
      a2[i]++; 
    for(int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) 
      System.out.println( 
        "a1[" + i + "] = " + a1[i]); 
  } 
}
```

it just displays some messages on the console and doesn't look any different than a C/C++ output. Is this really only like a C/C++ program, or is the VM still being invoked somehow in the background by Windows? I understand that the browser needs to have the VM installed for something like this to run

```
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 

public class Applet1 extends JApplet { 
  public void init() { 
    getContentPane().add(new JLabel("Applet!")); 
  } 
}
```

but what about other basic console based programs? And again, moving on to android, where exactly does the VM get invoked in it's case? Or should we consider the android OS as a very elaborate browser where the VM is running, and anything that we execute using our java code gets executed inside this VM?

Comment: the VM is part of the compiler. When you compile, the VM is called, and it is used to do the loading within the application. Even though it's simple, it is still being called

Comment: Whatever you are using to launch the Java program knows how to launch a Java program. If that requires invoking a VM, that's what it does.

Comment: so `javac` is the compiler, while `java` is the VM? Or is it that `java` invokes the VM? In that case, what is the `java` command doing? Is it just running my program, or does it also need to further compile the .class file?

Comment: javac ( compile ) does not invoke the VM, while java ( runtime ) invokes the VM. Just think JVM as an environment where you can execute your java program. Note that your java executable is the one that invoke the VM, which will running some task in your OS ( for example, Windows. ). This means Windows is not the one that invokes Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javac ( compile ) does not invoke the VM, It only converts your java codes to a bytecode. while Java ( runtime ) invokes the VM.

Just think JVM as an environment where you can safely execute your java program within your Operating System. Note that your java executable is the one that invoke the VM, which will running some task in your OS ( for example, Windows/Android kernel ).

This is why Java has a slogan "write once run everywhere" because as long as there is a JVM provided for an OS, the java bytecode will able to run in that OS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is this really only like a C/C++ program, or is the VM still being invoked somehow in the background by Windows?

When you interact with the console, you can't distinguish whether it's a Java or c/c++ program. But it's true your java source code has been compiled to byte code (.class file) and then run on JVM. You know the command `javac`, and there's another command called `java` which starts JVM and run your program.

In your case, when you run your program, the IDE invokes command `java` and the latter starts JVM on windows. JVM can interpret `System.out.println()` to show content on console by calling windows API.

> I understand that the browser needs to have the VM installed for something like this to run, but what about other basic console based programs?

In fact, we MUST install JVM on each OS before we can run any java program. For browser, it's just a plugin which calls the JVM installed on the OS. Like another windows media player plugin, you have to install a suitable windows media player first.

> And again, moving on to android, where exactly does the VM get invoked in it's case? Or should we consider the android OS as a very elaborate browser where the VM is running, and anything that we execute using our java code gets executed inside this VM?

So, android OS is not a browser but an OS. It has integrated JVM, for you can run java program at once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `.class` file is JVM bytecode. The JVM (invoked by `java foo` for `foo.class`) interprets (some JVMs [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) the bytecode into native machine code at runtime) the bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

Java compiler (javac) is implemented in Java, it's in jdk/lib/tools.jar. When we start javac it invokes JVM (JVM is implemented in native code, in case of Windows it's jvm.dll) and runs compiler classes with it.